# Ionic 1/Cordova 6.2.0 "Failed to load the webpage with error: unsupported URL" Error

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

We have an Ionic 1 app using Cordova that we are trying to get to work with Cordova 6.2.0. We have not updated this app for a few of years and apple emailed us telling us the app needs to be re-signed to work with iOS 14.5. I have updated Cordova to 6.2.0 and updated the plugins but can not get it to navigate pages using $state.go or any of the links to work. I get a popup saying "Failed to load the webpage with error: unsupported URL" and the error below in the console.

```
ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 8681, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}
```

The cordova-plugin-ionic-webview plugin is installed and the lines below are in the config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="fb:*" />
<allow-intent href="twitter:*" />
<allow-navigation href="twitter:*" />
<allow-navigation href="fb:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*://*" />
```

The Content Security Policy is

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

We are planing on rewriting the app over the next few months but we need to get this working for iOS 14.5 before we can finish the rewrite because it will probably come out in a few weeks.

Comment: did you have any luck with this. I'm having exactly the same issue, and none of the other solutions I've found on S.O. or elsewhere are working.

Comment: I did not. I ended up Rewriting the app in Ionic 5.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/issues/565
update or remove  cordova-plugin-code-push

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34805229)